# Differ between memos, appointments, tasks,... with C# and Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to use the **Lotus Notes COM Library** to access **NSF** files from a **.NET application**.
I am not a Lotus Notes export. How can I differ between the various Lotus objects/items like

***Memo, Appointments, Meeting Requests, Contacts, Distribution Lists, Tasks, Task Requests,
Journal, Mail Delivery Reports, RSS Items,...***

with the help of the Domino COM API? Can I read all these items with the API?
I didn't find this in the documentation (http://isotechhabitat.tryba.com/help/help85_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/781988d435f455bf85257607005f9f9c?OpenDocument)

I am missing a good description of the object model there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those objects are Notesdocuments. Each of them have a different value for their Form item that corresponds to their function. That is also how notes decides what form to use to display the document's contents.

So an meeting request might have its form item set to "Meeting Request" and the NSF would have a Meeting Request form within.

You can read all the items using the API to get the documents and then to get items using the getItemValue method.

To find only documents with one form you can use NotesDatabase.search and pass a selection formula of Form = "Meeting Request"